# How to implement Event handler interface in C#?

Tags: c#, interface, event-handling

I have an interface called IVideoPreparedListener that looks like this:

```
public interface IVideoPreparedListener
{
    void onVideoPrepared(Video video);
}
```

I have an even listener method in another class that looks like this:

```
public void setOnVideoPreparedListener(IVideoPreparedListener iVideoPreparedListener)
    {
        this.iVideoPreparedListener = iVideoPreparedListener;
    }
```

I'm trying to invoke this method by doing:

```
 videoPlayer2.setOnVideoPreparedListener(?)
```

The class which I'm invoking this method in, implements the event handler interface. I'm not sure what parameter should be passed inside the `setOnVideoPreparedListener` method so the interface method `onVideoPrepared` is invoked.
Normally in java I would do something like this:

```
ideoPlayer2.setOnVideoPreparedListener(new IVideoPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVideoPrepared(Video mVideo) {

                    //Pause current playing video if any
                    if(video.getIndexPosition() == mVideo.getIndexPosition())
                    {
                        if(currentPlayingVideo!=null)
                        {
                            VideoPlayer videoPlayer1 = videos.get(currentPlayingVideo.getIndexPosition());
                            videoPlayer1.pausePlay();
                        }
                        videoPlayer2.mp.start();
                        currentPlayingVideo = mVideo;
                    }


                }
            });
```

Any idea how I can do something similar with C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said the class that you're in implements the event handler interface. If so, then just call `ideoPlayer2.setOnVideoPreparedListener(this);`.

Comment: Yes that's what I actually did. Thanks :)